# How does Termination-Action and Session-Timeout work?

Tags: freeradius

I want to implement the ability to extend / stop the session.

I add entries to the radreply table:

```
Termination-Action := 1
Session-Timeout := 600
```

The session starts successfully (10 minutes), then I manually change the value:

```
Session-Timeout := 3600
```

I use the MikroTi router, after the expiration date (10 minutes) the session is simply broken, but there must be a new request to the RADIUS server? As far as I understand, a new session should be established, or the existing one should be extended without re-authorization.

For MikroTik there is a special parameter WISPr-Session-Terminate-Time, I tried to use it but it did not give results, tell me what am I doing wrong?

https://freeradius.org/rfc/rfc2865.html#Termination-Action

https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:RADIUS_Client

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the wonderful world of RADIUS, IETF RFC docs, and the word "MAY".  The NAS is not required to honour `Termination-Action` it's not even required to honour `Session-Timeout`, it can silently ignore both.

In the real world outside of the standards, most NAS will honour `Session-Timeout`, but simply disconnect the session after a period.

If you want something less disruptive, you'd need to implement something locally to track session lengths, and then send PoDs (Packet of Disconnects) to the NAS.  For PoDs to work, your NAS will need to support it, and you usually need to configure it explicitly.

See [RFC5176](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5176) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

I understand that the NAS may not support this feature, but does MikroTik belong to such devices? Moreover, the documentation describes the parameter WISPr-Session-Terminate-Time